# How to link button type="submit" in HTML?

Tags: html, css

Solution borrowed from this page:
https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-responsive-forms-with-flexbox--cms-26767

I have a button in a list:

```
<form>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="account.html" class="button">
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

I tried with this code:

```
<form action="account.html">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

but both methods don't work. What I have to do with my code to be able to link button to account.html page?

The CSS code:

```
a.button
{
    margin: auto;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    border: none;
    background: #333;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .09em;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-top: 2%;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: The first one doesn't need the `<button>` element at all, it's already a link.  The second one should work just fine, how is it failing?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you need a `<button>` in this case? Simply linking from one page to another is what we have regular links for. I'd recommend you use `<a href="account.html">` and style it to look like a button.

Comment: I found the solution here: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-responsive-forms-with-flexbox--cms-26767; This is form page to be filled by the user. I will do the back-end later to this. Will simply text between <a href="..."></a> be enough for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HMTL:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="account.html" class="button">Submit</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
a.button {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    border: none;
    background: #333;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .09em;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-top: 2%;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

**EDIT:**

HTML:

```
<form action="account.html" method="GET">
    <!-- Other fields -->

    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit">
            <!-- or -->
            <button type="submit" class="button">Submit</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
input.button {
    /* Your styles go here */
}

/* or */

button.button {
    /* Your styles go here */
}
```

Comment: It works for me, but shouldn't I use "<button type="submit">Submit</button>" type for submit button? Above this button I have a form to fill by user. Will it be ok if I just will put a linked text here and will I be able to merge it with back-end?

Comment: If you have a form, and the button is inside the form, then it's not what you want. I have edited my answer to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much for help. It solved my problem. Pozdrawiam z Krakowa ;)

Comment: Pozdrawiam również z Krakowa :)

Answer (score 0):

The second should work. However you can jump to input instead of button.

```
 <form action="account.html">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```